# loop multiple table from dataset

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have 2 table in my dataset, what i trying to achieve is convert 2 table item into string

```
Public Shared Function mtdCDsToStr(ByVal pDataSet As DataSet) As String
        Dim sDs As String
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder


        Dim drRow As DataRow
        Dim dcColumn As DataColumn
        Dim dtTable As DataTable
        Dim x As Integer = 0

        For Each dtTable In pDataSet.Tables
            For Each drRow In pDataSet.Tables(x).Rows
                Dim colName(pDataSet.Tables(x).Columns.Count) As String
                Dim i As Integer = 0
                For Each dcColumn In pDataSet.Tables(0).Columns
                    colName(i) = dcColumn.ColumnName
                    sb.Append(colName(i) + "," + drRow(colName(i)).ToString + ",")
                    i += 1
                Next

                sb.Append("|")
            Next


            x += 1
            sb.Append("$")
        Next


        sDs = sb.ToString

        Return sDs
    End Function
```

**code explanation**
the function is to pass in a dataset and convert the dataset into a string
what i trying to achieve is convert multiple datatable into a string but i can only loop one table in my code above, what should i do in order to loop multi table? =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change as below

```
For Each dtTable As DataTable In dataSet.Tables
    For Each dr As DataRow In dtTable.Rows
        For Each column As DataColumn In dtTable.Columns
            sb.Append(column.ColumnName + "," & dr(column.ColumnName).ToString() & ",")
        Next
        sb.Append("|")
    Next
    sb.Append("$")
Next
```

But rather than converting DataSet to string you may try to [**get XML**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.getxml.aspx) from DataSet. I'm Not sure What is the exact requirement you converting to sting, but XML will be good way to communicate Data.

```
xmlString =lpDataSet.GetXml()
```

Comment: hi @damith , there are error occurs with your code, the reason is because of my table(1) doesnt not consist of same column with table(0), and due to some reason, i need to keep some special characters in xml, so GetXml() doesnt good enough for me :(

Comment: oops, is my mistake i forgot to change one of the table to dtTable, already marks your answer as correct answer =)